# Add asynchronous functions to mysql

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I want to be able to update my search index in real time. This would be easiest done with triggers in MySQL. Adding code to the application, to update in each place the DB gets updated is very painful. The problem with triggers is that they slow down all updates/inserts/deletions to the DB.

Is there any way in which I can call a function that will run the update on the index (or just call a php script and that will then handle the updates) but do this asynchronously. It should not hold up the trigger from completing.

I am using MySQL for the DB and [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) for the search server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using gearman here:

http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9823

Use of the 'background' tasks, allows it to be asynchronous, and shouldnt delay the trigger much.

gearman makes calling PHP code from the trigger easy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer here and on the sphinx forum. Refer: http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9823 :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out some great ideas from [MySQL Events](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/)

and some more:
http://phpmaster.com/working-with-mysql-events/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=phpmaster-working-with-mysql-events

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html

Comment: Events are only run at certain time intervals. What I want is a way to be able to call a UDF function or a procedure from a trigger and then have that (the UDF or the pocedure) to run asynchronously so my trigger completes and the DB Insert/Update/Delete is completed quickly. I can then do the bulk of the work in the UDF or procedure and not have to worry about the delay this would add to DB changes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but it sounds like

`INSERT DELAYED`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html

and

`UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html

could be useful since those commands take the workload on the db into account.

Comment: Have explained to question better in the comment to Pentium10's answer.

Comment: Be careful ! As of MySQL 5.6.6, INSERT DELAYED is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release.